# Creating polling system to update my database users subscriptions

Tags: c#, queue, app-store, polling

I have an app which enables the user to subscripe for products and the subscripion renew monthely /yearly Depending on the plans.
My backend code is c# , and the subscriptions are created on App store .
I need my database to be updated once the user cancel his subscription on app store for example , it Should be cancelled in my database .
The other thing is that when an automatic renew for the subscription occures , it should be renewed also in my backend database .
I need to use a polling service in case if any one can support and article or structure of doing it , i am using Microsoft Azure .
I don't want to user server to server notifications on app store connect as i had found that they are not effient depending on that article .
https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/apple-subscription-notifications-are-almost-useless